# Recursive regex for closed parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in ruby to a pattern which should matches to following criteria

`/{{\d+}}/` double curly braces,with a number inside the it

`/.*{{\d+}}.*/` it can be preceded or followed by any number of characters

`/.*{{\d+}}.*\m/`  it can be multi lines

till this part it is working

it accepting strings like "afaf{{}}{{" , So I made changes as

`/(?:(.*\{\{\d+\}\}.*)\g<1>\m)/`  can have multiple `*{{number}}*`

eg.

```
empty string

xyz

{{345345}}

any thing{{234234324}}

<abc>{{234234}}<-

any chars{{234}}
{{234234}}any chars
{{4}}
```

not valid ones

```
{{non intgers}}

{{5345345}}{{

}}3345345{{

{345345}

{{34534}
}

4545

{234234

{{
5345
}}
```

but it's not working as expected.

Comment: Can the string contain standalone `{` and `}`? Try `/\A(?:[^{}]*{{\d+}})*[^{}]*\z/` if not.

Comment: no 
{ followed by {,  and properly closed with }}

Comment: Could you please clarify with an example? Please add to the question body. And please check if http://rubular.com/r/EuBB1IXqMH works.

Comment: it's so near
the only problem is it accepts stand alone { or }
{{234234}}} this invalid

Comment: But then the first one should work, see my first top comment. `/\A(?:[^{}]*{{\d+}})*[^{}]*\z/`

Comment: Why should `4545`  fail? Else, the [pattern above works](http://ideone.com/M0Ntka).

Comment: Ok, try [`rx = /\A(?:[^\d{}]*{{\d+}})*[^\d{}]*\z/`](http://ideone.com/Zj0fGX) if digits cannot appear outside of `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: great Job it works
add that in answers I will upvote it 
one more thing how to get better in grouping and recursions :)

Comment: You only need recursions when there are nested structures. E.g. when you want to match `{{99{{77}}88}}`. Here, you do not need a recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to need a recursion here, just use *grouping constructs* and *negated character classes* to make sure you do not match disallowed chars:

```
rx = /\A(?:[^\d{}]*{{\d+}})*[^\d{}]*\z/
```

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:[^\d{}]*{{\d+}})*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^\d{}]*`  - any 0 or more chars other than digits, `{` and `}`
  - `{{\d+}}` - `{{`, 1+ digits, `}}`
- `[^\d{}]*` - any 0 or more chars other than digits, `{` and `}`
- `\z` - end of string.

See the [Ruby demo test](http://ideone.com/Zj0fGX):

```
rx = /\A(?:[^\d{}]*{{\d+}})*[^\d{}]*\z/
ss = ['', 'xyz', '{{345345}}','any thing{{234234324}}','<abc>{{234234}}<-',"any chars{{234}}\n{{234234}}any chars\n{{4}}\n" ]
puts "Valid:"
for s in ss
    puts "#{s} => #{(s =~ rx) != nil}"
end

nonss = ['{{non intgers}}','{{5345345}}{{','}}3345345{{','{345345}',"{{34534}\n}", '4545', '{234234', "{{\n5345\n}}" ]
puts "Invalid:"
for s in nonss
    puts "#{s} => #{(s =~ rx) != nil}"
end
```

Output:

```
Valid:
 => true
xyz => true
{{345345}} => true
any thing{{234234324}} => true
<abc>{{234234}}<- => true
any chars{{234}}
{{234234}}any chars
{{4}}
 => true
Invalid:
{{non intgers}} => false
{{5345345}}{{ => false
}}3345345{{ => false
{345345} => false
{{34534}
} => false
4545 => false
{234234 => false
{{
5345
}} => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
(?m)^(?:(?:.+)?(?:{{)(?<NUM>\d+)(?:}})(?:.+)?)$
```

Test at https://regex101.com/r/WIuDhw/1/

Comment: "{{213123}}{{" this is not supposed to be valid string